# In Extjs 3 adding multiple components(toolbar and paging bar) in grid bottom bar?

Tags: extjs

I want to add toolbar and paging at gird bbar(bottom bar).
but if i add both in bbar array it comes in single line. what i need is paging in 1st line and toolbar in 2nd line.. anyone deal with these kind of probs before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
this.toolBar = new Ext.Container({
        height: 54,
        layout: 'anchor',
        xtype: 'container',
        defaults: {
            anchor: '100%',
            height: 27
        },
        items: [
            this.toolBar1,
            this.toolBar2
        ]
    });
```

and place this container in the the grid tbar or bbar.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. ya i already using this method only. but here we using one container and adding components in that container. what i'm seeking is directly adding two components in one bbar or tbar.